# Jquery Update Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this script that I have copied to my html file.
When I run it on fiddle combined with my html, it works.
But on my site, it doesn't.
Is this the correct way to include it?:

```
<!-- SCRIPT TO UPDATE PRICE -->
<script type="text/javascript>">
$('#quantity').change(function(ev){
var price = $('#quantity').val() * 0.1;
$('#price').html((price).toFixed(2));
});
</script>
```

This is how I have linked my jquery:

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv-se">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>ReClam Tryckeri i Uppsala</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"> <!-- Start of navigation menu div -->
<div class="container"><!-- 1-Start of container div -->
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="../index.php">ReClam Tryckeri</a>
<div class="navbar-header"><!-- 2-Start of navbar header div -->
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>

</div><!-- 2-End of navbar header div -->

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"><!-- 3-Start of navbar collapse div -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

<!-- CHECK IF START PAGE ACTIVE OR NOT AND CREATE LINK  -->
<li><a href='../index.php'>Erbjudanden<span class='sr-only'>(nuvarande)</span></a></li><!-- <li><a href="#">Trycksaker</a></li>  -->

<!-- GET TRYCKSAKER MENU -->
<!-- CHECK IF DROPDOWN ACTIVE OR NOT -->
<li class='dropdown active'><!-- BUILD THE PARENT MENU (STATIC) -->
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Trycksaker<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<!-- BUILDING THE CHILD ITEMS FROM DATABASE (DYNAMIC) -->
<li><a href="trycksaker.php?product_id=1">Flyers</a></li>
<li><a href="trycksaker.php?product_id=2">Affischer</a></li>
<li><a href="trycksaker.php?product_id=3">Foldrar</a></li>
<li><a href="trycksaker.php?product_id=4">Broschyrer</a></li>
<li><a href="trycksaker.php?product_id=5">Visitkort</a></li>
<li><a href="trycksaker.php?product_id=6">Korrkort</a></li>
<li><a href="trycksaker.php?product_id=7">Visitkort</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- GET SUPPORT MENU -->
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Support<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">Hur beställer jag?</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tryckfiler</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Villkor</a></li>
<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Kontakta oss</a></li>
<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Om oss</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!-- 3-End of navbar collapse div -->
</nav><!-- End of navigation menu div --><!-- BUILD COLUMN SYSTEM FOR CROSSDEVICE USABILITY -->
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-0 col-xs-0">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-0 col-xs-0">
<!-- BUILD PRODUCT INFO FROM DATABASE -->
<article>
<h3>Flyers</h3>
<hr><h4 class='text-justify'>Flyers är vår benämning på trycksaker som består av ett plant ark.</h4>
<!-- SCRIPT TO UPDATE PRICE -->
<script type="text/javascript>">
$('#quantity').change(function(ev){
    var price = $('#quantity').val() * 0.1;
    $('#price').html((price).toFixed(2));
});
</script>
<!-- BUILDING THE ATTRIBUTE FORM FOR THE OPTIONS -->
<hr>
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<!-- BUILDING THE FIRST OPTION STATIC-->
<select class="form-control">
<option disabled selected value>Välj Format</option>
<!-- OPTION 1 BUILDING THE CHILD ITEMS FOR THE ATTRIBUTES (DYNAMIC) -->
<option>A4&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;210x279mm</option>
<option>A5&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;148x210mm</option>
<option>A6&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;105x148mm</option>
<option>A7&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;74x105mm</option>
<option>A8&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;52x74mm</option>
<option>Card&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;85x55mm</option>
<option>High&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;75x210mm</option>
<option>Stand&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;100x210mm</option>
<option>Square&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;105x105mm</option>
<option>Half&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;105x210mm</option>
<option>Long&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;105x297mm</option>
<option>Cd&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;120x120mm</option>
<option>Box&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;148x148mm</option>
<option>Frame&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;160x160mm</option>
<option>Dvd&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;183x273mm</option>
<option>Full&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;210x210mm</option>
</select>
<br>
<!-- BUILDING THE PRINT OPTION STATIC-->
<select class="form-control">
<option disabled selected value>Välj Tryck</option>
<!-- PRINT OPTION 1 BUILDING THE CHILD ITEMS FOR THE ATTRIBUTES (DYNAMIC) -->
<option>4+0&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ensidigt Färgtryck</option>
<option>4+4&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dubbelsidigt Färgtryck</option>
</select>
<br>
<!-- BUILDING THE SECOND OPTION STATIC-->
<select class="form-control">
<option disabled selected value>Välj Pappersvikt</option>
<!-- BUILDING THE CHILD ITEMS FOR THE ATTRIBUTES (DYNAMIC) -->
<option>90g/m²</option>
<option>115g/m²</option>
<option>135g/m²</option>
<option>170g/m²</option>
<option>250g/m²</option>
<option>350g/m²</option>
</select>
<br>
<!-- BUILDING THE THIRD OPTION STATIC-->
<select class="form-control">
<option disabled selected value>Välj Papperstyp</option>
<!-- BUILDING THE CHILD ITEMS FOR THE ATTRIBUTES (DYNAMIC) -->
<option>Silk</option>
<option>Gloss</option>
</select>
<br>
<!-- BUILDING THE QUANTITY OPTION STATIC-->
<select class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" >
<option disabled selected value>Välj Antal</option>
<!-- BUILDING THE QUANTITY ATTRIBUTES (DYNAMIC) -->
<option>250</option>
<option>500</option>
<option>750</option>
<option>1000</option>
<option>1500</option>
<option>2000</option>
<option>2500</option>
<option>5000</option>
<option>7500</option>
<option>10000</option>
<option>15000</option>
<option>20000</option>
<option>25000</option>
</select>
<br>
<!-- CREATE THE INPUT FIELD FOR MARKING -->
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder='Märk din order med ett arbetsnamn. Exempelvis "Inbjudan Fredde"'>
<br>
<!-- CREATE THE UPLOAD AND ORDER BUTTON -->
<label class="btn btn-info btn-file">
Bifoga Tryckfiler <input type="file" style="display: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>
</label>
<div style="float: right;">
<button class="btn btn-primary">Lägg i varukorgen <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></button>
</div>
<!-- FINISHING THE OPTION FORM -->
</div>
<!-- CREATING THE CHOICE ALERT AREA -->
<hr>
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>×</span></button>
Priset uppdateras automatiskt när du gjort dina val ovan.
</div>
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" id="price" name="price"></div>

<!-- CREATING THE PRICE AND IMAGE AREA -->
</div>
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<!-- CREATING THE LINK FOR IMAGE -->

<img src='../images/Flyers.jpg' alt="Flyers"></div>
<!-- ADD AN EMPTY DIV RIGHT FOR EMPTY WHITE SPACE ON DESKTOP -->
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-0 col-xs-0">
</div>
</div>
</article>
</div><!-- End Container Div) -->
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to wrap her inside document ready function. :D

Comment: I have done so, I have also moved the script into the header area. I have another test jquery that works on the same page as this script that is working but this one is not. reclam.se/index2.php – Kaki Sami 9 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the script code inside **document.ready(function(){..})**

```
<script type="text/javascript>">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#quantity').change(function(ev){
         var price = $('#quantity').val() * 0.1;
         $('#price').html((price).toFixed(2));
       });
    })
</script
```

Comment: I have done so, I have also moved the script into the header area. I have another test jquery that works on the same page as this script that is working but this one is not. http://www.reclam.se/index2.php